# how to restore a deleted web application which included site as well as content database in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: web-application

Is it possible to restore the deleted web application which was deleted with the options to delete the Content Database and the IIS web sites.

Comment: Did you have any backup of the deleted content database?

Comment: no backup for it.

Comment: is there any solution?

Comment: You don't have any sql backups or anything? If not i'm pretty sure there's nothing you can do.

Comment: Do you have windows backup on sql server?

Comment: yes it worked that way. i had windows backup. restored it and moved it to the latest windows version. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have deleted your Web Application along with the content then there is no way to recover your deleted web application except if you have a Content Database backup or Windows Backup. If you would have deleted the web application without content then with Content Database in SQL Server you would have reattach it using `Mount-SPContentDatabase` PowerShell Command.

Comment: i agree. my bad

Answer (score 2):

If you have the Windows Backup then you can still restore the Web Application.

- Restore the datadrive from backup and you will get your SQL content Database back.
- Now create a DB from data file, once database restored
- Now create web application then mount the restored DB to this web app.

Comment: yes added :) :)